# Помогите с mysql запросом с подсчетом данных из другой таблицы

Tags: mysql, mysqli

помоги вывести данные, вот запрос который использую

```
SELECT g.`name_ru-RU` as nameship, 
      (SELECT COUNT(c.id) 
         FROM `crm` c 
         WHERE c.`dostavka` LIKE '%g.`name_ru-RU`%'
      ) as totalcrm 
  FROM shipping g
```

ошибка происходит вот в этом месте

```
LIKE '%g.`name_ru-RU`%')
```

если убираю g.`name_ru-RU и вставляю текст то все норм, но мне нужно чтобы он искал по этому столбцу

Comment: `like concat('%', g.name_ru-RU, '%')`

Comment: спасибо, забыл про него вообще)

Comment: Лучше `WHERE LOCATE(g.name_ru-RU, c.dostavka)` или `WHERE INSTR(c.dostavka, g.name_ru-RU)`. Зачем лишний вызов функции?